# How to execute a Python function within a function and not stop the execution

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to accomplish something **without using threading**

I'd like to execute a function within a function, but I dont want the first function's flow to stop. Its just a procedure and I don't expect any return and I also need this to keep the execution for some reasons.

Here is a snippet code of what I'd like to do:

```
function foo():

    a = 5

    dosomething() 
    # I dont wan't to wait until dosomething finish. Just call and follow it

    return a
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really.  One interpreter implies one (and only one) thing executing python bytecode at once.  Your options are to fire it off in a new thread or process.  Or, well, you could rewrite everything using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) I guess, but that's hardly everyone's cup of tea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html to achieve fire-and-forget behavior.

```
import concurrent.futures

def foo():
    a = 5

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(dosomething)
        future.add_done_callback(on_something_done)
        #print(future.result())

    #continue without waiting dosomething()
    #future.cancel() #To cancel dosomething
    #future.done() #return True if done.

    return a

def on_something_done(future):
    print(future.result())
```

### [updates]

*concurrent.futures* is built-in since python **3**

for Python **2.x** you can download [futures 2.1.6 here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures)

Comment: Sadly I'm using 2.8 and that is a 3.x feature

Comment: I found this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures back port for python 2.7 by Alex Grönholm. didn't test it myself but looks to be same as python3.

Comment: there is a little known multiprocessing.ThreadPool you can use in 2.7.

Comment: It will not `return a` until executor is done. Questions was "I dont want the first function's flow to stop"

Answer (score 1):

Python is synchronous, you'll have to use asynchronous processing to accomplish this.

While there are many many ways that you can execute a function  asynchronously, one way is to use [python-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq). Python-rq allows you to queue jobs for processing in the background with workers. It is backed by Redis and it is designed to have a low barrier to entry. It should be integrated in your web stack easily.

For example:

```
from rq import Queue, use_connection
def foo():
   use_connection()
   q = Queue()
   # do some things
   a = 5
   # now process something else asynchronously
   q.enqueue(do_something)
   # do more here
   return a
```